# how to extract MAX value after query?

Tags: sql, sql-server

I've tried several answers from stackoverflow, guessing I didn't understand the concept.
The main idea is to get the maximum salary in my zoo database

after the query:

```
SELECT EMPLOYEE_BASE_SALARY+EXTANDED_SALARY AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM ZOO_EMPLOYEE JOIN ZOO_TRAINER_EMPLOYEE 
ON ID=TRAINER_EMP_ID
```

I receive the table:

TOTAL_SALARY

```
7700
7000
6800
4800
4800
```

I've tried:

```
select max(SELECT EMPLOYEE_BASE_SALARY+EXTANDED_SALARY AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM ZOO_EMPLOYEE JOIN ZOO_TRAINER_EMPLOYEE 
ON ID=TRAINER_EMP_ID)
```

I've tried:

```
SELECT TOP 1 * FROM(
SELECT EMPLOYEE_BASE_SALARY+EXTANDED_SALARY AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM ZOO_EMPLOYEE JOIN ZOO_TRAINER_EMPLOYEE 
ON ID=TRAINER_EMP_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL_SALARY DESC)
```

Comment: both my attempts got errors.

Comment: Have you had a look at the documentation for `MAX`? If you look at the errors, they will tell you the problems as well.

Comment: the error was (as always I get in sql - which i hate it) error near (or next to)  ')'

Answer (score 0):

You need to use the max function:
Its a minor alteration of your first trial. The first try listed all salaries. You specify that you what the max of that list

```
SELECT max(EMPLOYEE_BASE_SALARY+EXTANDED_SALARY) AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM ZOO_EMPLOYEE JOIN ZOO_TRAINER_EMPLOYEE 
ON ID=TRAINER_EMP_ID
```

Comment: Thank you.
such a simple solution. I got stock on getting the table and then use it.

Answer (score 0):

The syntax is wrong where you try to get the `TOP 1` row.
Try this:

```
SELECT TOP 1 EMPLOYEE_BASE_SALARY+EXTANDED_SALARY AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM ZOO_EMPLOYEE JOIN ZOO_TRAINER_EMPLOYEE 
ON ID=TRAINER_EMP_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL_SALARY DESC
```

Answer (score 0):

Either query can work.  The first has the closing paren in the wrong place and an extra `SELECT`, so it should be:

```
SELECT max(EMPLOYEE_BASE_SALARY+EXTANDED_SALARY) AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM ZOO_EMPLOYEE JOIN
     ZOO_TRAINER_EMPLOYEE 
     ON ID = TRAINER_EMP_ID;
```

The second has the `ORDER BY` in the wrong place and no alias for the subquery.  But, because no subquery is needed, you can try this instead:

```
SELECT TOP (1) EMPLOYEE_BASE_SALARY + EXTANDED_SALARY AS TOTAL_SALARY
FROM ZOO_EMPLOYEE JOIN
     ZOO_TRAINER_EMPLOYEE 
     ON ID = TRAINER_EMP_ID
ORDER BY TOTAL_SALARY DESC
```